# Collections.sort() is not getting called/executed i.e not entering this method only

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am making use of Collections.sort() method to sort a list of records based on time field.But my program execution is not entering this method only. 
I am getting a list of treatment object records from my database which I'm storing in **list** variable.
I'm filtering these records based on some parameters and I'm storing the filtered in a list **dosages** which is of DosagaData type.
After this I need to sort the filtered list based on **time** field for which I made use of Collections.sort() which is not getting called.

'''

```
private List<TreatmentObject> list;
private List<DosageData> dosages;

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
DosageData dosage = new DosageData(list.get(i));
System.out.println("Dosage data is" +  dosage);
if(dosage != null) {
   dosages = new ArrayList<DosageData>();
   dosage.dosageTime = time;
   System.out.println("DosageData time is " + dosage.dosageTime);
   this.dosages.add(dosage);
   this.dosageCount += 1;
  }
}

Iterator<DosageData> dosaegDataIterator = dosages.iterator();

while (dosaegDataIterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println("Before Sorting " + dosaegDataIterator.next().dosageTime);
}

Collections.sort(dosages, new Comparator<DosageData>() {
@Override
public int compare(DosageData first, DosageData second) {
System.out.println("Inside Dosage Sorter Class");
Date firstDate = null, secondDate = null;
String firstTimes = first.dosageTime;
System.out.println("First time is" + firstTimes);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");
try {
   firstDate = sdf.parse(firstTimes);
   System.out.println("First date is" + firstDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
   String secondTimes = second.dosageTime;
   System.out.println("Second time is" + secondTimes);
try {
   secondDate = sdf.parse(secondTimes);
   System.out.println("Second date is" + secondDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Return result is" + firstDate.compareTo(secondDate));
return firstDate.compareTo(secondDate);
}
});

for (DosageData dosage : dosages) {
   System.out.println("After Sorting" + dosage.dosageTime);
}

System.out.println("Sorted Dosages is" +dosages);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
dosages = new ArrayList<DosageData>();
```

You create a new list **per** DosageData object that you have created. So when that list that you intend to sort ... contains exactly one element (because you put all prior DosageData objects into separate lists, to then throw those lists away.

A list with one entry can be sorted without calling any method of your Comparator.

Beyond that, there are many things really wrong about your code:

- first of all: format/indent it in reasonable ways. Messy code makes it easy for you to overlook bugs.
- don't use 3 different methods to iterate your lists. The straight forward way to iterate such collections is to use *foreach*, like: `for(Treatment treatment : list) { ...` . No need to use a manual for loop, no need to use an iterator!
- it is a really bad idea that the Comparator has to know the **format** that your timestamps have.

Leading to: keep in mind that your `compare()` method might be called **many** times. Now note that this method is creating a data formatter, and does parsing for two dates. Each and any time it gets called. That isn't a problem when you have say 100, or 1000 entries in your list. But if you are talking about 100K list elements, then *anything* you do in `compare()` matters performance wise. Thus: when you are dealing with large lists, consider to rather have your class implement the `Comparable` interface, and to compute that timestimp only once, at creation time of the object, to avoid the repeated formatting and parsing.

In other words: your design would be much cleaner if a DosageData object already contained a real Date object, instead of *other* code having to constantly parse/format strings. All that code needs to know what format to use. That is a bad idea!

Finally: it is 2019. Learn about the wonderful new Date/Time classes that were added with Java 8! You might also want to learn about streams, as your whole initial code can be written as

```
private List<DosageData> dosages = list.stream()
  .map(t -> new DosageData(t))
  .collect(Collectors.asList());
```

That's it.

Comment: `map(DosageData::new)`

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new ArrayList within the for loop: `dosages = new ArrayList<DosageData>();`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    DosageData dosage = new DosageData(list.get(i));
    System.out.println("Dosage data is" +  dosage);
    if(dosage != null) {
       dosages = new ArrayList<DosageData>();  // ***** HERE ******
       dosage.dosageTime = time;
       System.out.println("DosageData time is " + dosage.dosageTime);
       this.dosages.add(dosage);
       this.dosageCount += 1;
      }
}
```

and so this list will hold one and only one DosageData item. There's no need to sort an ArrayList within only one item, and Java knows this.

Solution: create the ArrayList **before** the for loop.